# Error: Expected a “;” Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++

I have a mistake in my source:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE mod, DWORD DWORD_GRUND, LPVOID res)
{
```

The "{" is undelined with the mistake:

> Error: Expected a “;”

Could you please help me?

Comment: We need some more context.  Probably from before that function declaration line.

Comment: Please show the complete code for that function.

Comment: The issue could be in code before that line or it could be missing `#include`s.

Comment: Visual Studio in your title isn't needed, this problem is independent of an IDE. (just FYI:)

Answer (score 3):

You might miss a closing `}` in the function before this line. Make sure they all match well.